# Problem loading shared library using dyn.load on R Linux, but equivalent Windows build works fine

Tags: r, shared-libraries, hdfql

I've built a [package](https://github.com/mkoohafkan/hdfqlr) for interacting with HDFql from R. It relies on the R wrapper and DLLs/SOs provided by HDFql 2.1.0. The packages works perfectly in Windows using the DLLs, but for some reason the HDFql library SOs fail to load in a Linux environment. I've tried this both on [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/mkoohafkan/hdfqlr) and on a local Docker Linux/R container.

The relevant code contained in the function [`hql_load()`](https://github.com/mkoohafkan/hdfqlr/blob/246ab1737448993017583127f2751bfa8ca77a2a/R/connect.r#L132) is below. Assume that HDFql is extracted to a folder in the current directory "/hdfql-2.1.0", which means that

`dllpath = c("/hdfql-2.1.0/lib/libHDFql.so", "/hdfql-2.1.0/wrapper/R/libHDFqlR.so")`

I check that these paths exist using `normalizePath(dllpath, mustWork = TRUE)` and also check that the objects load successfully and appear in `getLoadedDlls()`.

```r
# ... starting at line 153 of connect.r ... #
wrapper.file = tempfile(fileext = ".r")
  wrapper.lines = readLines(wrapperpath)
  writeLines(wrapper.lines[-grep("dyn\\.load", wrapper.lines)],
    wrapper.file)
  # load DLLs
  for (dll in dllpath) {
    dyn.load(dll, local = FALSE, now = TRUE)
    if (!dll %in% sapply(getLoadedDLLs(), function(x) normalizePath(x[["path"]], mustWork = FALSE))) {
      stop("Error loading HDFql shared library object ", dll)
    } 
  }
  # load wrapper
  wrapper = new.env(parent = .BaseNamespaceEnv)
  tryCatch(
    sys.source(wrapper.file, envir = wrapper, toplevel.env = packageName()),
    error = function(e) {
      stop("Failed to execute HDFql R wrapper.\n Additional Information:\n",
       e)
    }
  )
  assign("wrapper", wrapper, envir = hql)
  invisible(NULL)
}
```

**The error occurs in the `sys.source` call** to evaluate the code in the wrapper file provided by HDFql, and **specifically in the initialization call**. The wrapper contents are below; note that in my function above I remove the `dyn.load` calls from the wrapper before evaluating it (the libraries are loaded beforehand).

```
hdfql_operating_system = Sys.info()["sysname"]
if (hdfql_operating_system == "Windows")
{
    dyn.load("HDFqlR.dll")
    hdfql_shared_library <- "HDFqlR"
} else if (hdfql_operating_system == "Linux")
{
    dyn.load("libHDFqlR.so")
    hdfql_shared_library <- "libHDFqlR"
} else   # macOS
{
    dyn.load("libHDFqlR.dylib")
    hdfql_shared_library <- "libHDFqlR.dylib"
}
rm(hdfql_operating_system)



#===========================================================
# INITIALIZE HDFQL R WRAPPER SHARED LIBRARY
#===========================================================
hdfql_initialize_status = .Call("_hdfql_initialize", PACKAGE = hdfql_shared_library)
```

> Error: Failed to execute HDFql R wrapper.
>
> Additional Information:
>
> Error in eval(parse(wrapper.file), envir = wrapper): Could not find/load HDFql shared library 'libHDFql.so'!

**I have been troubleshooting this for weeks with little progress. Can anyone tell me why the library is not loading correctly in Linux systems?**

Comment: What is the error message? Have you added the location of the SO files to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: @RalfStubner I updated my post with the error message, which is quite vague. Can you explain the use of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? The HDFql wrapper instructions do not discuss this setting and my understanding was that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is for DLLs that are included or built by the package. The HDFql library is not installed with the package; it is an external program. The package uses `dyn.load` with the full path to access the shared library.

Comment: @RalfStubner actually I see now that `LD_LIBRARY_PATHS` is discussed in the HDFql manual. I will review and see if I can resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion by @RalfStubner was correct: the issue was setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on the Linux machine to include the HDFql libraries. Interestingly enough, I still had to provide the full qualified path names to the DLLs in the `dyn.load` call and could not use `Sys.setenv` or the `DLLpath` argument to `dyn.load` to temporarily modify `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`---instead I had add a line to my `travis.yaml`/`Dockerfile` to update `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${HDFQL_DIR}/lib:${HDFQL_DIR}/wrapper/R:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I still don't understand why I could not resolve the issue using e.g.

```r
Sys.setenv(LD_LIBRARY_PATH = paste(dirname(dll), Sys.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH"), sep = ":")
```

or

```r
dyn.load(basename(dll), DLLpath = dirname(dll))
```

since both of these commands should (in theory) modify the search path to include the HDFql directories. **I would appreciate any answers that could explain this.**

I was also surprised to find that once I updated `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` I was hit with environment bindings and namespace issues that never came up on the Windows build---but that's a separate issue.