# Which shared library is R finding?

Tags: r, shared-libraries

How can I find out which shared library R has found? My present situation is as follows:

We are attempting to provide an R environment with several different interfaces, while providing as much consistency as possible (e.g., we would like to have the same libraries available in all interfaces): we can invoke R from a console, we can run RStudio, and we can run R notebooks under Jupyter notebooks. All three interfaces are supported by the same Unix-alike hardware and operating system (RedHat). Different users have different interface preferences.

Under our current configuration, we can run R from the console and load the `vroom` package just fine:

```
$ R
> library(vroom)
> # no news is good news
```

However, under current conditions, `library(vroom)` fails under our RStudio setup:

```
> library(vroom)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘vroom’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
  unable to load shared object '/PATH-PREFIX-REDACTED/miniconda3-1/envs/r/lib/R/library/vroom/libs/vroom.so':
  miniconda3-1/envs/r/lib/R/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /PATH-PREFIX-REDACTED/miniconda3-1/envs/r/lib/R/library/vroom/libs/vroom.so)
```

The error from RStudio gives me a clue about why it is failing. But how can  I find out why the console version is *succeeding* (which `libstdc++.so.6` did it find)?

I have read a little (on StackOverflow [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494585/setting-ld-library-path-from-inside-r), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57279598/problem-loading-shared-library-using-dyn-load-on-r-linux-but-equivalent-windows)] and elsewhere [[3](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#dyn_002eload-and-dyn_002eunload)]) about how `dyn.load` might be working, but I still do not understand why the consolde R successfully loads `vroom` when none of the `libstdc++.so.6` on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` have `GLIBCXX_3.4.30` (according to my understanding of the output of `objdump -x`).

### Additional Information

The `.libPaths()` is the same in both "console" and "RStudio" R:

```
> .libPaths()
# [1] "PATH-PREFIX-REDACTED/R_LIBS_SITE/R4.2"                 
# [2] "PATH-PREFIX-REDACTED/miniconda3-1/envs/r/lib/R/library"
```

AFAICT (`ls <directory>`), the *vroom* package is installed under only the "miniconda" path of `.libPaths()`, so I am afraid @Mikael-Jagan's point is sorta moot (however, +1 for pointing out the new-to-me tool of `ldd`): apparently the same `vroom.so` is being loaded under "console" and "RStudio"  R. **And now I am more confused,** because shouldn't the vroom package then be finding the same `libstdc++.so.6` in either case?

```
$ # PATHNAMES, USER NAMES, AND GROUP NAMES HAVE BEEN CHANGED
$ # TO PROTECT THE INNOCENT.
$ # REFORMATTED FOR LEGIBILITY ON A WINDOW OF USUAL SIZE.
$ pwd
/PATH-PREFIX-REDACTED/miniconda3-1/envs/r/lib/R/library/vroom/libs/
$ ldd vroom.so | grep 'libstdc*'
libstdc++.so.6 => /PATH-PREFIX-REDACTED/miniconda3- 
        1/envs/r/lib/R/library/vroom/libs/../../../../libstdc++.so.6 
        (0x00002b2277b8a000)
$ cd /beohome/a/ScientificProgramSupport/local/miniconda3- 
        1/envs/r/lib/R/library/vroom/libs/../../../..
$ ls -lF libstdc*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 admin admin       19 Oct 25 15:51 libstdc++.so -> 
        libstdc++.so.6.0.30*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 admin admin       19 Oct 25 15:51 libstdc++.so.6 -> 
        libstdc++.so.6.0.30*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 admin admin       19 Oct 28 12:38 libstdc++.so.6.0.21 -> 
        libstdc++.so.6.0.24
-rwxrwxr-x 3 admin admin 12212840 Oct 23 06:08 libstdc++.so.6.0.30*
$ objdump -x libstdc++.so.6 | grep ' GLIBCXX_3\.4\.30'
32 0x00 0x0297f840 GLIBCXX_3.4.30
0000000000000000 g     O *ABS*  0000000000000000
        GLIBCXX_3.4.30
```

**And now I am even more confused**, because it looks to like `ldd` and `objdump` together are telling me that `GLIBCXX_3.4.30` *is* part of the `libstdc++.so.6` that `vroom.so` should find.

Comment: How are you installing these packages? Are these all running on the exact same machine? It sounds like you may be installing from source which may compile differently on different machines.

Comment: What is the output of `.libPaths()` in each environment? You may have **vroom** installed in two places and built differently in each place, in which case you can do `otool -L /path/to/vroom.so` to learn where each library is finding symbols.

Comment: Added info on `.libPaths()` per prompting of @MikaelJagan.

Comment: @MikaelJagan I don't think we have `otool`: `man otool`, `info otool`, and `type otool` indicate as much.

Comment: So you are using miniconda? Is that how you installed the packages? Are you using conda environments? The conda didistributions of R aren't the official distributions so things don't always seem to work correctly with this.

Comment: Oops - that was a typo, because I've been using macOS lately.  I meant `ldd /path/to/vroom.so`, but my suggestion might be moot if the same shared object is loaded in both environments.

Comment: @MrFlick RE miniconda, etc.: Yes, using miniconda for most of our R stufff (a few packages are not available via miniconda and are installed in other ways, e.g., `install.packages`). Pretty sure we used conda to install vroom---there is a vrrom subdirectory under `.../miniconda3-1/envs/r/lib/R/library`. Yes, using conda environments (one called "r", in this case).

Comment: I have provided additional information in the post, but I want to stay focussed on the actual question, which is still important to me: **Which shared library is R finding?** (some `libstdc++.so.6` in this case, but which one?)